# Roberval's Method and Tangent Construction involving parabola $y^2=4ax$

Tags: calculus, math-history

**Problem:**
Let $u$ denote the distance of a moving a point
$P$ on the parabola $y^{2}=4px$ from the directrix $x=-p$ and from
the focus $\left(p,0\right)$. If the point moves in such a way that
$u^{\prime}=x^{\prime}=1$ (unit horizontal speed), show that the
tangent vector $\overline{t}$ show in the figure is $\overline{t}=\left(2x/\left(x+p\right),y/\left(x+p\right)\right)$
, while the actual velocity vector of $P$ is $\overline{v}=\left(1,\sqrt{p/ x}\right)$.
Then show that $\overline{t}$ and $\overline{v}$ point in the same
direction, but 
$$
\left\Vert \overline{t}\right\Vert =2\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+p}}\quad\text{while}\quad\left\Vert \overline{v}\right\Vert =\sqrt{\frac{x+p}{x}}.
$$

[image]

**Here's what I have so far:** 
 we parametrize $y^{2}-4px=0$, by letting $x=pu^{2}$
and $y=2pu$ we have parametrized the parabola with respect to parameter
$u$. Now, let the curve $\boldsymbol{c}\left(u\right)=\left(pu^{2},2pu\right)$.
Taking, the derivative, we have 
$$
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}\left(u\right)=\left(2pu,2p\right).
$$
I want to obtain $\overline{v}$ from this, but I'm not sure how,
so here's what I did. 
$$
\mathbf{c}^{\prime}\left(u\right)=2p\underbrace{\left(u,1\right)}_{\overline{v}???}.
$$
So, I just guess (but I'm note sure why) 
\begin{align*}
\overline{v} & =\left(u,1\right)\\
 & =\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{p}},1\right)\quad\left(\text{since }x=pu^{2}\right)
\end{align*}
then, 
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert \overline{v}\right\Vert  & =\sqrt{\frac{x}{p}+1}\\
 & =\sqrt{\frac{x+p}{p}}
\end{align*}
which isn't quite what's expected in the problem above. Where am I
going wrong? Also, I'm not sure how to derive $\overline{t}$. I'm assuming that it's obtained by first normalizing the vector from the focal point $F$ to $P$ as well as the vector from the directrix to $P$, then summing these two vectors gives us $\overline{t}$, but I'm not sure how to formulate these vectors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim of the task is to show that Roberval's method gives a tangent vector in the sense of modern calculus.  Roberval determines two forces that keep a point on the parabola and claims that the sum of those two forces $\bar t$ is tangent to the parabola.  Quite clever.

The first force is the vector emanating from $P$ in $x$-direction of length $1$, thus $(1,0)$.  The second one also emanates from $P$ in direction $FP=(x-p,y)$.  Now to keep the point on the parabola, the second vector must have the same length as the first, i.e., $1$.  You'll easily calculate (using $y^2=4px$) it's length to be $x+p$.  Finale: adding both forces gives the Roberval-vector $\bar t$.  From here you may calculate $\|\bar t\|$.

The last step is to show that Roberval's $\bar t$ is indeed tangent in the sense of modern calculus. Now your velocity vector $c'(u)$ luckily satisfies
$$c'(u)=(2pu,2p)\parallel(2pu^2,2pu)=(2x,y)\parallel\frac{1}{x+p}(2x,y)=\bar t.$$

We are essentially done!  Good ole Rob was right. (Of course we cannot hope that $\|\bar t\|=\|c'(u)\|$, because $\|c'(u)\|$ heavily depends on the parametrization choosed. So comparing the lengths is somewhat ... unnecessary.)

Comment: something doesn't add up here. I believe the the first force vector, call it $\overline{w}$ should be $(1,0)$. Now, for the second force vector, call it $\overline{v}= FP/|FP|$, we have $\overline{v}=((p-x)/(x+p),y/(x+p))$, then summing $\overline{v}$  and $\overline{w}$, we have $(2p/(x+p),y/(x+p))$, which isn't quite what we want.

Comment: changing the first force vector to $(x-p,y)$ seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed up the coordinates.  Very nice question anyway.  I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The point moves with unit speed in the *horizontal* direction, so $\mathbf{c}'(u) = 2pu(1, 1/u)$, and $\bar{v} = (1, 1/u)$.